# Why some capabilities are disabled in Apple account - Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

Tags: configuration, certificate, provisioning-profile

When I create an app identifier in my Apple account, I find some capability disabled. Some capabilities can be checked/unchecked but others are not. For example App Group, Push notification are disabled.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is your role Admin, Agent or just Developer?

Comment: Where can i know that? i am logged into an account created by others. @NicolasMiari

Comment: Account > Membership > Membership Information > (near bottom) Your Role

Comment: I am also enrolled to my company's program without special privileges. I am listed as "Member". Otherwise should be "Admin" I think.

Comment: I am in Admin role. I am using a wildcard pattern for app bundle id. Does it cause issue?

Comment: YES, I'm afraid it does. Some services require a fully specified bundle ID (no wildcards), so you need to change that. On the other hand, as an admin, you have full privileges to create/modify artifacts (certs., etc.)

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem was wildcard, but when I am creating fixed bundle id, In app purchase service is on and cant be changed. Do you know why?

Comment: I think InApp purchase is on by default for all AppIDs, and if you don't need it you just don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/Certain entitlements are only available when you use explicit bundle IDs for the app.  Ensure that when you are creating your bundle ID for the app that you do not use the wildcard (*) at the end of your bundle ID.

From [Apple's Q&A on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1713/_index.html):

[image]